# JMeter not recording an ADF application

Tags: jmeter, oracle-adf

I am following the below link to configure JMeter for Oracle's ADF 11g. I am not able to record the ADF Application deployed on WebLogic Server ver 10.3.6 using JMeter 2.10. My JDeveloper version is 11.1.2.4.

http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/configuring-apache-jmeter-specifically.html

Answer (score 0):

The document looks good but I see some weird Test Plan structure. I would suggest to do the following:

1. Record your use case via JMeter HTTP Proxy server
2. When you'll get set of "interesting" HTTP requests you'll need to deal with dynamic values as it's described in the guide. The key point is that [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) is a **Post Processor** so it must be **a child** of HTTP Request.
3. JSESSIONID cookie is handled by HTTP Cookie Manager, there is no need to append it to the URL. Just make sure that you have **CookieManager.save.cookies=true** property. It can be found in *jmeter.properties* file under /bin folder of your JMeter installation.

So you need to implement next steps:

- Record some HTTP Requests
- Extract viewstate and other dynamic stuff from first request via Regular Expression Extractor Post Processor and save it as JMeter Variables
- Use variables instead of recorded hard-coded values

You can inspect requests and responses via "View Results Tree" listener, it's able to demonstrate request and response headers, cookies, timings, etc. and response data to assure that you've reached desired page in your flow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, as you suggested I have set the CookieManager.save.cookies property to true. But JMeter HTTP Proxy Server is not recording any of the transactions carried out using the ADF application and I'm unable to figure out the reason. So unless it records anything I cannot proceed with the rest of your valuable suggestions. Please help.